# Why won't hashcat accept this RAR3 hash?

Tags: passwords

I am using hashcat in straight mode trying to crack a RAR3-hp hash that I obtained using John the Ripper (rar2john) of a RAR file. I put the hash into the program, but the error "Line-length exception" is presented with no hashes loaded when trying to run the arguments below.

```
hashcat -a 0 -m 12500 -w 3 -o output.txt "$RAR3$*1*HASHHERE" wordlist.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [hashcat developers](https://hashcat.net/forum/thread-5334-post-28950.html#pid28950), hashcat doesn't support "$RAR3$*1*" hashes, just "$RAR3$*0*".

You can use john to crack this hash, it probably will take a little bit longer but at least works.

Answer (score 0):

Hashcat 6.2.2 now supported `type=1` , I think you may try now

Comment: Are you sure? I'm using Hashcat 6.2.5 and I get "Token length exception" as well.